# Stack trace in Xcode 5 won't work

Tags: xcode, debugging, xcode5

Has anyone experienced this in `Xcode5`? All my threads when debugging only shows the top stack entry.

I remember this bug from Xcode 4, but back then it was just a Xcode quit and relaunch. Now that doesn't work. I've tried everything. Even restarted my mac.

Any ideas?

[image: Wierd stack trace]

Comment: Have you moved the scale slider so it shows more detail? If it's all the way to the left, it may not show much. (It's the slider below the stack frames.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a slider at the bottom of the navigation panel, move it to the right.

[image]

Comment: OMG! Thanks. Never ever in my life seen that slider. Thanks!